# Cannot resolve symbol "locationListener" - Android

Tags: android, location, locationlistener

I am having trouble implementing a `LocationListener`.

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Address;
import android.location.Criteria;
import android.location.Geocoder;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView latitudeTV;
    TextView longitudeTV;
    TextView altitudeTV;
    TextView locationNameTV;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    double altitude;
    String locationName;

    LocationManager locationManager;
    Location location;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        latitudeTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latitude);
        longitudeTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longitude);
        altitudeTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.altitude);
        locationNameTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.locationName);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }

        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 0, locationListener);

        location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        onLocationChanged(location);

        LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                longitude = location.getLongitude();
                latitude = location.getLatitude();
                altitude = location.getAltitude();
                locationName = "Placeholder";

                longitudeTV.setText("Longitude: \n" + longitude + "°");
                latitudeTV.setText("Latitude: \n" + latitude + "°");
                altitudeTV.setText("Altitude: \n" + altitude + "m");
                locationNameTV.setText("Location: \n" + locationName);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

            }
        };
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if it's a syntax issue or a scoping issue, but I keep getting "unable to resolve symbol" errors. It's acting like I haven't implemented the `LocationListener` methods. I have tried adding `implements LocationListener` to `MainActivity` and that shows an error saying I have not implemented the `LocationListener` methods. I'm not sure where my mistake is.

EDIT:

I've changed my code per your answers. When I try to implement `//locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE, 5000, 0, this);` I get the following when trying to launch the app: `LocationTestApp keeps stopping`. I've commented out that line, and the app works again.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {

    TextView latitudeTV;
    TextView longitudeTV;
    TextView altitudeTV;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    double altitude;

    LocationManager locationManager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        latitudeTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.latitude);
        longitudeTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.longitude);
        altitudeTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.altitude);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if (checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && checkSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }

        //locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE, 5000, 0, this);

        Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        onLocationChanged(location);

    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
        altitude = location.getAltitude();

        longitudeTV.setText("Longitude: \n" + longitude + "°");
        latitudeTV.setText("Latitude: \n" + latitude + "°");
        altitudeTV.setText("Altitude: \n" + altitude + "m");
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {

    }
}
```

Comment: When you implement an interface you need to implement the methods. Add it again as an interface to MainActivity and then generate the methods automatically.

Comment: Modify your line like this: `public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener` and click on that line. Then hit Alt+Enter and go to 'implement methods'. Add them and then you shouldn't have an error for not implementing them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `LocationListener` class, in this case an Activity, should be defined as below:

```
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LocationListener {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ...
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 0, this);  // Note: You pass this, so the overridden methods
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        // Do your stuff here
    }


    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}
}
```

And this is the solution in jle's comments.

But if you want to use the `locationListener` that you've declared in your onCreate, you should declare it before using it, in this way:

```
...onCreate(...) {
    ...
    LocationListener locationListener = new LocationListener() {...} // Define this...

    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 5000, 0, locationListener);   // ...and then call this

    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    onLocationChanged(location); 
}
```

Comment: I've edited my code per your answer, and now my app crashes upon launching. See my edited question for the code.

Comment: Please check for errors in your logcat, the "LocationTestApp keeps stopping" should have a motivation, written with something like "Caused by..." in your Logcat

Comment: Thanks, it appears the provider was missing from my `requestLocationUpdates` call. I instead added these lines of code `Criteria criteria = new Criteria();`
       `criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);`
        `String provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);` and now it works exactly as expected when I call for updates using `locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 5000, 0, this);`